# Should the marvel/DC-comics tag be changed to just marvel/DC?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Marvel has long ago moved past only supplying comics for its audience, and now boasts a thriving film and TV section as well. The same can be said about DC.

I think that by changing the tag to just, for instance, [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) we'd clear up a lot of tag issues (non-comic Marvel questions tagged with [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics), [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) questions not also tagged with [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics)).

---

Completed, but [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) is still a *synonym* of [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and the same for [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) and [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) to prevent misuse and confusion.

Comment: I get paid by the tag, so the more the merrier.

Comment: Despite the consensus here that [tag:marvel] and [tag:dc] are better tag names than [tag:marvel-comics] and [tag:dc-comics], the synonymisation made in Aug 2012 was the wrong way round. (I suspect this might have been an unintentional mistake - the UI for creating tag synonyms is far from intuitive, especially when it comes to which way round the synonym is done!) I've now switched the synonyms and marked this as [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 11):

I agree that the [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) tag seems unwieldy.  It would make a bit more sense if it was intended to distinguish between Marvel Comics, Marvel Studios, Marvel Productions, Marvel Entertainment, etc., but do we really need that level of distinction?

[marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) should be the combination used for questions pertaining to Marvel comic titles. That way, the [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) tag can also be used for questions specifically pertaining to non-comic titles under the Marvel franchise.

Comment: After asking a handful of comic questions yesterday I found myself thinking the same thing as all comics questions get both [tag:comics] and [tag:marvel]/[tag:dc], so the second half seems redundant.