# Should [dc-movies] be merged into [dc]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Now that we have the top-level tags [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) for questions about any Marvel or DC properties, there's been some chat about whether we need certain subtags. Obviously it's worth having subtags for individual films or TV series within the overarching Marvel/DC universes, but we don't have tags specifically for comics-based Marvel/DC questions: [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics) and [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) are synonyms of [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel) and [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) respectively, as discussed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1706/31394), and comic-specific questions can be tagged with [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) as well if necessary. But **what about tags specifically for movies?**

I've been [told](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=35995285#35995285) that the [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) tag *is* worth keeping, since it's not just the same as [marvel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel)+[movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie). I've also been [told](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=35988643#35988643) that the [dc-movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-movies) tag is *not* worth keeping. If this is the case, I can easily merge it into [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc), thus removing it from all questions (and ensuring they're all tagged appropriately with the DC tag) without any manual edits required. But given my utter ignorance of all things Marvel and DC, I want to be absolutely sure that this is the right thing to do.

### Should the [dc-movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-movies) tag exist, or should it be merged into [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes

Dc-movies appears to have been used due to confusion about the dc-comics tag. So, people have used it instead of dc-comics + movie, perhaps thinking dc-comics referred to comics only. That is part of the reason we renamed dc-comics to just dc.

Even if that's why people used dc-movies, it's not really being used correctly. The questions it's attached to seem to specify that the question is about a movie. However, that's not even the correct use of the movie tag, and the individual work tags already tell us it's a movie. (The correct use of the movie tag is to specify format for ID questions or to limit scope to only movies if you're asking about a franchise that's on many formats.)

The movies in question are either *not* part of a collective universe, like dcau or dceu, and so it doesn't represent such a tag (and is unneeded), or they *are* part of such a shared universe and they were already tagged accordingly during the big cleanup event a couple weeks ago (and it's still unneeded).

Lastly, its extremely limited use leads me to further believe its use is accidental, with people using it only when unsure how to tag the question.

In short, the tag seems to be an accident, and serves no real purpose.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm pretty sure we're at the threshold of "Number of people who even care" ;)

Comment: With +6/-0 on this answer, I've gone ahead and done the merge, together with a synonymisation.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, a thousand times - yes!

To add to @CreationEdge's answer and @Randal'Thor's point about [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) being worth keeping, I'd like to point out that we have a corresponding tag for the DC cinematic universe - [dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe). While it may not be the best choice of a name, I do believe it is what some of the question tagged with [dc-movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-movies) should actually have.

Comment: It's not *my* point about the MCU tag - I'm just repeating what other people have told me :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor point here, point there :)

Comment: The only point I've got here is the one on the end of my sword.

Comment: @Randal'Thor [sword you say](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9f/17/26/9f17260ee263d33f6024d189b83796d2.jpg), eh?

Comment: `dc-extended-universe` *should* be on all relevant questions. I went through that during the tag clean up. I removed `dc-movies` from some at that time, too, but those that already had dceu I didn't bother with, because we were hoping for this merge.